# How to completely reinstall Wolfram Workbench on linux

Tags: workbench

I've messed up my Ubuntu install, I've changed some pathnames I shouldn't have (don't know which ones exactly though), and after that Wolfram Workbench was not launching anymore. I uninstalled it by erasing the folder /usr/local/Wolfram and the workspace, then reinstalled it at the same place.

Workbench is now launching but the editor is still messed up, as you can see in this screenshot, this is all I get and I can't interact with:

[image: screenshot]

When I launch Wolfram Workbench via command-line, I get the messages:

```
(Wolfram Workbench:5188): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed

(Wolfram Workbench:5188): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed

(Wolfram Workbench:5188): LIBDBUSMENU-GTK-CRITICAL **: watch_submenu: assertion `GTK_IS_MENU_SHELL(menu)' failed
```

Do you know what is causing this and what I can do to reinstall Workbench properly?

Comment: Did you remove the preferences directory `/home/.../.eclipse`? Maybe it helps to clean it completely.

Comment: Yes it helps... That's the folder I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete the folder /home/.../.eclipse and problem will be solved.